# c++ o appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, constructor

someone know why I get this error "'Shape': no appropriate default constructor available" and what can I do?

```
Circle::Circle(const Point& center, double radius, const string& type, const string& name):
    _center(center), _radius(radius)
{
    this->_name = name;
    this->_type = type;
}

Shape::Shape(const string& name, const string& type):
    _name(name), _type(type)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Circle::Circle(const Point& center, double radius, const string& type, const string& name):
    Shape(name, type), _center(center), _radius(radius) {}
```

In the constructor initializer list, you need to specify the parameters for the base classs' constructor. If you don't, the compiler would try to use the default constructor, but apparently `Shape` doesn't have one.